# Remove values from Map while comparing the values against a List

Tags: java, java-8

Beginner QQ : I have a list and a Map
. I need to check all the values in the "Map" against the "List", if the value is in Map BUT NOT IN the List then  i need to remove it

```
    List<String> list = getRequiredList();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list)
    Map<String, String> map = getMap();
```

need some info on how to remove from the map if its not in List

Comment: `map.putIfAbsent(str);` isn't valid - Are the values in your list representative of the map's keys, or the values?

Answer (score 7):

A neat thing about Maps is that the [key set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) and [value collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) are both backed by the Map itself.  What this means is that removing a key from the key set effectively removes it from the Map it belongs to.

Therefore, you can use [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) on the key set:

```
map.keySet().retainAll(list);
```

That will make sure that the only keys in the Map are the Strings which are in your List.